# ui-router nested state and intermediary guard

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

According to [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-create-rules-to-prevent-access-to-a-state), you can use a custom data and listen for `stateChange`s to prevent accessing the state based on some condition. This works without a trouble but my use case is, when I'm entering a nested state I want all of the descendant states rules be enforced.

In other word, if I'm starting from `green` state and I want to end up being in `blue` state, I want the `login` rule gets evaluated. Currently, only `color` rule is applied. Is there any way to do this?

I understand that the data is overwritten on child state, and that's the reason that I only see the `color` log. But what is the way to extend `data` and not overwriting it?

[image: example]

here is the code:

```
var example = angular.module("example", ['ui.router']);

example.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("parent", {
            url: "/parent",
            templateUrl: "templates/parent.html",
            data: {
                rule: function () {
                    console.log("login rule checked");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        })
        .state("parent.child", {
            url: "/child",
            templateUrl: "templates/child.html",
            data: {
                rule: function () {
                    console.log("color rule checked");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
});


example.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (!toState.data || !angular.isFunction(toState.data.rule)) return;
        var result = toState.data.rule();
        if (result) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go(toState, result.params, {notify: false});
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but doing this:

```
$state.go(toState, result.params, {notify: false, reload:true});
```

will ensure that the entire state is reloaded including all parent states.  It's not exactly what you want since it may reload more than you want if state R is not the top of the tree. However, this should work in the example you are showing.

For more information, see the [ui-router API](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

Comment: Still doesn't log the `login rule checked`. Am I missing something?